# Python file scan application with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, file, mongodb, multiprocessing

How to use multithreading in this code and limit the thread; example 4 thread.

```
import os
import glob
from pymongo import Connection
from gridfs import GridFS

db = Connection().microfilm
fs = GridFS(db)

def scandirs(path):
    for currentFile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*') ):
        if os.path.isdir(currentFile):
            print 'Entering directory: ' + currentFile
            scandirs(currentFile)

        base, ext = os.path.splitext(currentFile)
        if ( ext == '.tif'):
                print "Processing file: " + currentFile
                fName = os.path.basename(currentFile)
                with open(currentFile) as gfsFile:
                        oid = fs.put(gfsFile, content_type="image/tiff", filename=fName)

scandirs('./')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pool(list) of Thread objects of size `n`, use [is_alive](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) to check if any is finished, so then you can assign a new directory scan in it.
Also you should subclass the `Thread` class and define a `run` method to adapt to your problem, details on how to do this are in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

first import Threading then Threading.**init**() which part u want to put in thread name it run()(This is the overridden method of base class Thread) or Thread(target="your threaded function",args=[]) call start method with thread object.